# Colour fill column B where column A is not empty, and so on

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

In Google Spreadsheets I need column B to change color if and only if there is something in column A and column C changes color if there's something in B...etc.  I'm trying to write the conditional formatting but it only seems to do things to the one column regardless of the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example might have helped, but I'm guessing you might find this useful:

[image: SO26240427 example]